# COMException: This process has already been attached. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013132E)

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm using `MdbgProcess` and `MdbgEngine` to write information to an XML file like the application version, process id, time, threads, etc. I have the following code:

```
MDbgProcess mdbgProcess = null;
    try
    {
        MDbgEngine debugger = new MDbgEngine();
        debugger.Options.StopOnExceptionEnhanced = true;
        mdbgProcess = debugger.Attach(info.ProcessID);
        mdbgProcess.Go().WaitOne();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

But when I try to execute this line: `mdbgProcess = debugger.Attach(info.ProcessID);`, I'm getting this exception: `COMException: This process has already been attached. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013132E)`.

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you've already got a debugger attached to the target process?  You can only attach one at a time.

Comment: @JamesThorpe How do I know if it already has?

Comment: Catch and handle that exception?  Even if there is way to check if something was attached already, if the check says "no", by the time you try to attach, something else may well have done so you need to handle the exception anyway

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ok, is it also possible that the visual studio debugger is already attached to the process and I'm attaching another?

Comment: It's certainly possible.  You're the one running it, you tell me :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ok, I currently don't want to add logic to test if the visual studio debugger is attached or to detach it. I'm thinking of running the program from a deployed application. It's a sure thing that the visual studio debugger is not attached, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80261/discussion-between-jmc-and-james-thorpe).